# Check if field exists in DB using SQL trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database **Users** that has four fields: **Name**, **Client**, **ID**, **Time**. **Client** is an integer (0-99). How to write a trigger that will find latest user from **Users** (latest according to **Time**) during *Insert* and if the **Client** of this user equals **Client** of inserted user then I'd like to *Rollback*

I tried like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DoubledData ON Users
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @client DECIMAL(2)
DECLARE @client_old DECIMAL(2)
DECLARE @name Varchar(50)
SELECT @name = Name from inserted
SELECT @client = Client from inserted

//This doesn't work, "Syntax error near Select":
SELECT @client_old = Select top(1) Client from Users where Name like @name order by Time desc;

IF @client = @client_old
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
END
```

The problem is that I can assign same values to Client for one user but they can't be one after another (eg for client this order is correct 1-2-3-1-3 -> order is important, but this isn't correct: 1-2-3-3 -> after 2nd occurrence of '3' in a row it needs to be rollbacked)

I'm using MS SQL

[EDIT]
I have found that I can execute it without **Select top(1)** like:

```
SELECT @client_old = Client from Users where Name like @name order by Time desc;
```

But the trigger doesn't execute afer *insert*

Comment: Can you explain what is not working ? which value do you have ? Wich one do you expected ?

Comment: I cannot set @ client_old in: SELECT @ client_old = Select top(1) Client from Users where Name like @ name order by Time desc; It looks like I can't use Select in this case so I don't know how to assign it (I had to use spaces) // Incorrect syntax near Select

Answer (score 3):

First, you clearly don't understand triggers in SQL Server and the `inserted` pseudo-tables.  These can have more than one row, so your code will fail when multiple rows are inserted.  Sadly, there is no compile check for this situation.  And code can unexpectedly fail (even in production, alas).

Second, the right way to do this is probably with a unique constraint.  That would be:

```
alter table users
    add constraint unq_users_name_client unique (name, client);
```

This would ensure no duplication, so it is a stronger condition than your trigger.

Comment: The problem is that I can assign same values to Client for one user but they can't be one after another (eg for client this order is correct 1-2-3-1-3 -> order is important, but this isn't correct: 1-2-3-3 -> after 2nd occurrence of '3' in a row it needs to be rollbacked). Or is there any other way to check it as sending a request for last User to DB is not effective

Comment: @extra2 you should put this very important info with your question. The way I understood your original question this answer would be correct, but now you change the question in this comment. Please edit your question and put this info there